# ASP.NET button does not fire on the first click

Tags: c#, asp.net, web, webforms

I've already digged in the topic from a lot of websites and cant find a solution.
Whenever i click the button, it does not fire on the first click, but on the second. I have tried several things, but nothing seems to work.

Any help is appreciated.

Here is the code of the button:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnPeliculas" runat="server" Text="ABM peliculas" CssClass="btn-primary text-center" Height="50px" Width="200px" Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="Medium" OnClick="btnPeliculas_click" />
```

the onClick function is the following:

```
protected void btnPeliculas_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
                Server.Transfer("frmwPeliculas.aspx");
        }
```

NOTE: I have also tried different web navigators and nothing seems to work.

Comment: Were you able to hit the breakpoint on click event on first click while debugging the code?

Comment: No, only on the 2nd.

Comment: Please show the source for your CSS `btn-primary` class. I think  there might be something going on there. If in doubt, remove your CssClass attribute for now to see if a single click works.

Comment: .btn-primary {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #337ab7;
  border-color: #2e6da4;
}     I tried and it doesnt affect the problem. Thanks though!

Comment: Start a fresh project with just a button and its click event. See if that requires two clicks. If it doesn't then you can start to try to figure out what's different; if it does then post the entire sample here for further review.

Comment: Try Wrapping `Server.Transfer` in `if(IsPostBack){}` ?

Comment: Try setting the button property for UseSubmitBehavior="False" and the postback should happen to trigger the onclick code.

Comment: Thank you all for your help but nothing seems to work. @Jazimov, I tried what you suggested, and it required only one click. Same seems to happen with the previous web form. Lets see if I can explain myself, I have a web form, with username and password, once they are entered correctly, the submit button redirects the user to an options page (takes 1 click), with 3 buttons. All of them, whichever i click, require two clicks to access the other page. Note: Each button redirects the user to another web form. Ex: button 1 redirects me to webform 1, button 2 to webform 2 and button 3 to webform 3.

Comment: USER AND PASS WF                                                                                protected void btnIncioAdmin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
                if (this.txtP.Value.ToString() == "admin" && this.txtU.Text == "admin")
                {
                    Server.Transfer("frmwOpciones.aspx");
                }

                else
                {
                    this.lblMensaje.Text = "Usuario o password incorrecto";
                }           
        }

Comment: 3 BUTTONS OPTION WF   protected void btnPeliculas_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (IsPostBack)
            {
                Server.Transfer("frmwPeliculas.aspx");
            }
            else
            {
                this.lblmensaje.Text = "Error!";
            }
                         
        }protected void btnSeries_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Server.Transfer("frmwSeries.aspx"); }
      protected void btnGeneros_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {       Server.Transfer("frmwGeneros.aspx");
        }

Comment: That's encouraging--progress! Best thing to do: Don't use comments for code--edit your original post with the new content and I/others will check again. Thank you for your clarifications and additional detail.

Comment: @Jazimov thank you for your support and to everyone who suggested an answer. I'm going to use an achor instead of and ASP button and see what happens.

Comment: It worked! Probably there was an autopostback happening there with the button. Thank you all for your help!

Comment: This really isn't a solution. Also, up-vote people who help you--words of thanks go only so far. :)